# SharePoint List Item View/Read Permission

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, nintex-workflow

I am actually new to SharePoint permissions stuff. I really need someone help to guide me or give me a hint.

I have a SharePoint 2013 list, with items. User create a item using Nintex forms and when item is created, Nintex Workflow get trigger.

The idea behind this list is, User A will create a item then User B will review it and approve/reject.
After User A create item, item permission should change to 'Read' so that user A doesn't change any value of item until user B take some action.

In Workflow, I am changing the item permission using 'Set Item Permission' action and setting permission as Read.

But the problem is after

1) User A created item, he is not able to view/read item but able to edit item.
I selected item through list and click on 'view item' through ribbon, I am getting error 'Sorry, you don't have access to his page'.
I clicked on eclipse of item, selected Shared with->ADVANCED I am seeing the user A have view/read permission.
Then I made sure through 'Workflow history' if action got executed or not, it seems action got executed successfully.

This is really weird how user is able to edit item but not able to view item?

I really appreciate if anyone can provide any hint or help to make item readable.

Answer (score 1):

Can you click on the list item, and check permissions for that item. You can click on Shared With -> Advanced. Then from the ribbon choose Check permissions. Enter the User A name and see what permissions he has.

And if he has more than Read, it means workflow has not finished its job. So check the workflow. It should break any inheriting permissions on that list item and then set unique permissions for only User B. This will take away the permissions from User A.

Comment: I am not sure what was the issue, because same list same workflow I deployed in UAT/Staging, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

A second approach would be to make a form status column and connect it to submit button.

Return a value eg. Submitted to the column once the form is submitted by A.

Now in nintex form designer,select the control and add rule to disable the control if form status == "Submitted".

Comment: I am not sure what was the issue, because same list same workflow I deployed in UAT/Staging, it is working fine.